# How do I fix a black screen when I delete a Navigation ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am attempting to delete a Navigation ViewController from Xcode application. When I delete from the Main.storyboard file, the app screen is black when I run the application(it's not because it is loading).

How can I successfully de-integrate a Navigation ViewController from my Xcode application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no initial view controller in your storyboard after you delete the navigationVC

You need to select VC that you what to load first and check IsInitialVC

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. I knew it was something super simple I was missing. I feel dumb now. Thanks for the help!