# Xcode iOS simulator shows black screen when launched

Tags: swift, xcode, build, simulator

I know that there are multiple other StackOverflow posts about the same issue, but none of the solutions seem to work. All of a sudden, when I build my app, it successfully builds, shows the launch screen, then shows a black screen. I am currently pretty far in with the app, so it is quite complex. There are only 4 minor warnings (no errors of course), so I highly doubt that it is a coding problem in my project. When the black screen appears, the battery and time at the top of the simulator screen disappear as well. Here is what I have tried:

- quitting and restarting Xcode + simulator
- cleaning build folder on Xcode
- changing the size of the simulator
- erasing all content and settings
- removed all breakpoints
- double-checked that the main interface is correct
- changed the initial view controller
- selected a different simulator device (to check if it were just one of the simulators)
- tried using a real device (which just resulted in the error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (that is beside the point))

As you can see, I've tried many things, but to no avail. If there are any other solutions, please let me know since I am quite desperate at this point.

The links below bring you to screenshots of what is happening.

[The project successfully builds, and as you can see, there are only 4 warnings (regarding another storyboard not visible in this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZOu.jpg)

[The simulator shows the launch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY8a9.jpg)

[This is what the black screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cELCq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I was building my app in Xcode. Everything was going well, then all of a sudden a black screen kept coming up instead of my initial view controller.

The solution to my issue was selecting the view controller that loads as a black screen, then going in the right tool bar and checking the "Is Initial ViewController" button under the "View Controller" tab.

I am not sure if your issue is this simple, but I hope it helped.

My question for reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112039/how-do-i-fix-a-black-screen-when-i-delete-a-navigation-viewcontroller)

Comment: How do I know which view controller is the one that loads as a black screen?

Comment: Also, I've already tried switching the initial view controllers. Thanks for you help btw

Comment: The first View Controller you expect to load should be your initial view controller. I think the initial should be your View Controller Scene, not the Nav Controller. I would also make sure your Xcode is updated (just another idea).

Comment: Right now the initial view controller is the Navigation controller that controls the sign up/log in. I’ll keep looking for answers. Also, my Xcode is version 13.5, not sure if that’s the most updated version. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah keep the initial view controller as the nav controller, I was wrong about that. Please comment if you find a solution, as I would like to know now.

Comment: I left it alone for the rest of the night, made sure that the inital view controller and main interface was correct, then went to sleep. The moment I woke up, I ran to my computer to see if anything changed. By logic, nothing should have been fixed, but for some reason, the simulator no longer showed a black screen. I think that it was purely a glitch in the Xcode software, so if anyone else encounters this problem, do not worry, take a break for a couple of hours (exit xcode/simulator, turn off and plug in your computer), and the simulator should be back to normal.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a legit solution, but this was what "worked" for me.

Answer (score 0):

it's AppDelegate problem i was facing the same issue for quit long time now when i changed my app delegate to run my project on lower version than ios 14.5 when adding @available(iOS 13, *) didn't solve the problem for me i changed the AppDelegate file to the old one "that didn't contain any SeneDelegate code" so final AppDelegate should look like this,

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    
    return true
    
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you find that all your applications in simulator are dark, you can switch out of dark mode by going into Settings -> Developer -> Toggle Dark appearance off.